# Escaping Question Mark in Tuckey Url rewriting (XML/Regex)

Tags: java, regex, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I want to permanent redirect

```
/?industry_id=3 to /industry/3/athletics
```

I tried the rules :

```
 <rule>
    <from>/?industry_id=3$</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">/industry/3/athletics</to>
 </rule>

 <rule>
    <from>/&#63;industry_id=3$</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">/industry/3/athletics</to>
 </rule>


 <rule>
    <from>/\\?industry_id=3$</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">/industry/3/athletics</to>
 </rule>

 <rule>
    <from>/\?industry_id=3$</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">/industry/3/athletics</to>
 </rule>
```

But without success.

I tried this one :

```
 <rule match-type="regex">
    <note>Request page is deprecated</note>
    <condition type="query-string">industry_id=3</condition>
    <from>/</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">/industry/3/athletics</to>
 </rule>
```

which is working for the rewrite but then I got a "too many redirect" because of other rules i guess, even though the parameter last="true" is set

Answer (score 1):

That seems strange. The following worked for me:

```
<rule>
  <condition type="query-string">page=download</condition>
  <from>/</from>
  <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">/downloads</to>
</rule>
```

You must have some other interfering rule as you also mentioned.

Comment: Yes i think it is probably the case thanks for your suggestion BoneGoat, what seems weird through is that last is equals to true so it shouldn't interfering without other rules logically